# iOS Enterprise distribution warning message

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise

I have an iOS application that I am distributing using the enterprise distribution method (posting the IPA file to a website). When a user installs the application there is a warning message that reads:

> Are you sure you want to open the application "Application Name" from Developer "iPhone distribution certificate name"

The client is asking if there is any way to change that alert message so that it does not read "iPhone distribution"

I am assuming that at some point in the future Apple is going to change the "iPhone distribution/development" certificate to "iOS", but in the mean time is there anyway to change that warning message?

Comment: i'm usually seeing "URL would to install Appname"

Comment: This is the message after the install, when the user launches the app for the first time. Not the install message ...

Comment: What kind of certificate are you using for signing? I've only tried this with Ad-Hoc Certificates, and it def doesn't happen that way.

Comment: Distribution Certificate Ad-hoc for enterprise distribution (if its just an ad-hoc build it does not give the message, but if you set it for enterprise distribution then you get this warning message...)

Comment: Then why do you build for enterprise distribution? it works just as well with manually created ipa's and plists.. :)

Comment: You can manage the users of the app with the enterprise distribution ... Somebody leaves the company you can zap their access :)

Comment: how can you do that? besides revoking their devices access? Some special website?

Comment: Have the app call in on launch to check in and see if "still valid" if no "lock app" ...

Comment: I stumbled upon this 'issue'. It is purely cosmetic, but it would be nice just to show the developer name.

Comment: This is a custom message sent from the server side settings on the Enterprise Store servers that you are using. You will have to ask the MDM teams that you're using to change the custom install message for their Enterprise Devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard message. This would be displayed when the app is started for the first time only and not on the subsequent launches. This is an information message which is displayed when app is distributed using adhoc profile enterprise license. This is for the user to check and trust the distributor or else the user can quit and delete the app.